# Best continuous integration software

Tags: svn, testing, tfs, hudson

I am currently looking for a good software for project management. I need the software to:

- build code at every SVN commit
- run unit tests once a day
- run functional tests once a day
- run coverage once a day
- store builds
- run FxCop once a day
- integrate with Jira

My candidates are Hudson (aka Jenkins), Sonar, Bamboo, TeamCity, TFS.

I will need this system for C# Developement.

As far as I know each of these systems is able to fulfill my requirements, the only point I am not sure abut is Jira integration (for example in case of TFS).

I am hoping you will help me choose between these programs to make the life od developement team easier not harder.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What you are looking for is ["continuous integration"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration), not project management. However, Stack Overflow is not well suited to "What is the best..." type questions.

Comment: Depends what you mean by "integrate with Jira", but basically Jenkins can do all of these.

Comment: I don't think you want to use TFS as it's all or nothing. To take advantage of Team Build you'd really need to migrate your code out of SVN and in to TFS. Don't get me wrong, as an all in one solution TFS 2010 is pretty good (and significantly better than previous versions.) but I don't think it meets your requirements. I'd go with Jenkins if SVN is your source control tool

Answer (score 3):

Jenkins will definitely do all this for you (I would choose Jenkins over Hudson since something like 95% of the project committers moved to Jenkins from Hudson when it was forked).

Sonar is a code quality metrics tool and won't do any of the items in your list - it will display static analysis and code coverage data but won't actually produce that data for you.  Sonar does have [integration with Jenkins](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Sonar%2bplugin), so you can use it to display your projects' quality metrics.

I'd recommend Jenkins over the other solutions you mentioned because it's free (although you can buy a [commercial version with support](http://www.cloudbees.com/jenkins-enterprise-by-cloudbees.cb) if you need it) and integrates with many more tools than the other solutions.